# Strange serial prints - ESP8266 Wifi Web server

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am working on a web server project on the ESP8266, using Platform and the Arduino libraries. 
My dependencies include ESP8266WiFi, ESP8266WebServer, tzapu/WiFiManager.

In my serial monitor, I keep seeing strange prints I did not put there myself. Here is an example :

```
:wr 57 0
:wrc 57 57 0
:wr 16 0
:wrc 16 16 0
:wr 17 0
:wrc 17 17 0
:wr 669 0
:wrc 669 669 0

:wr 269 0
:wrc 269 269 0
:wr 9 0
:wrc 9 9 0
:ack 57
:ack 536
:ack 444
:close
```

Does anybody know what these are, where they come from, and how to get rid of them ?

Here is part of my code (`setup()` in in `main.cpp`)

```cpp
void setup(void) {
    /* Set up logger */
    gLogger = &Logger::instance();

    /* Init relay */
    gRelay = new elec::Relay(LED_DIO, elec::RELAY_MODE_NORMAL);

    /* Init Switch */
    gSwitch = new elec::Switch(SWITCH_DIO);

    /* Init WiFi manager */
    gWiFiMgr = new WiFiManager;

    /** Set callback that gets called when connecting 
     * to previous WiFi fails, 
     * and enters Access Point mode */
    gWiFiMgr->setAPCallback(configModeCallback);

    /* Disable debug mode for the WiFiManager */
    gWiFiMgr->setDebugOutput(false);

    if(!gWiFiMgr->autoConnect(AP_NAME, AP_PASSWD)) {
        *gLogger << "[ERROR] Failed to connect to WiFi !" << endlog;
        ESP.reset();
        delay(1000U);
    }
    *gLogger << "[BOOT ] Successfully connected to " << WiFi.SSID() << endlog;
    *gLogger << "[BOOT ] IPv4 Address : " << WiFi.localIP().toString() << endlog;

    /* Set up web server */
    gServer = new WiFiServer(80U);
    gServer->begin();

    /* End of setup */
    *gLogger << "[BOOT ] System booted !" << endlog;
}
```

Comment: post your complete code. Not sure why you need both ESP8266WiFi and WiFiManager.

Comment: Because it is required, as ESP8266WiFi is a dependency of WiFiManager, as per [the instructions in the projects README.md](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: That's doesn't mean a must. I would suggest you read the [documentation](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.3/esp8266wifi/server-examples.html) and understand what's ESP8266.h can offer. Anyway, without knowing you code, no one know how you implement it.

Comment: I have read that documentation. I use the ESP8266Wifi in my code to read and write. WiFiManager is used to setup the network to connect to without having to define the SSID and Psswd in the code. 

One of these frameworks prints things on the serial port without me explicitly ordering these prints. My logs appear normally. 

The specific implementation is not relevant, as these prints are not mine. So it has to be a framework’s doing. The only code that plays with them is the setup, which has been added to the main post. Otherwise it’s just client->close, client->print, client->available.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you ever found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was due to enabling "Debug Level: CORE" in Arduino IDE. Once I set it to None, these stopped.